# ArcGIS JavaScript API find the polygon a point belongs

Tags: polygon, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, point-in-polygon, spatial-query, query-task

I have a shapefile containing polygons and whenever a user searches an address I store latitude and longitude of the location. I want to know which polygon this address belongs and I have id assigned for each polygon in the shapefile. But I am new to ArcGIS API I couldn't figure it out. I tried this:

```
var queryCitiesTask = new QueryTask({
    url: "https://****/gridpointspolygon/MapServer/1"  
});
var query = new Query();
query.geometry = new Point(long, lat); // 
query.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS; 
query.outFields = ["pt_v03_ind"];
query.returnGeometry = false;
queryCitiesTask.execute(query, function (result) {
    console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: Are your "shapefile" polygons in the "gridpointspolygon/MapServer/1"?  Is that layer also on the map?

Comment: Polygons are there but not on map